# Take first row grid in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get first row only in grid, because if i using `document.getElementById("grid").rows.length == 1`
it is not work when the grid length is more than 1, because i want put validation on first row only. If the length is more than 1, the validation does not work.

Comment: Could you please post your html and state more clear what exactly you want? Thanks

Comment: Post code please no help based off info

Comment: Best guess would be `document.getElementById("grid").rows[0]` but without more info it is just a guess

Comment: In fact that does work - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google chrome browser select that row with mouse, then inspect element and copy css path and put that css path in your selector.

[How can I get the CSS Selector in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without looking at the code but here it is more or less.

```
var table = document.getElementById('table_id');
var first_row = table.querySelector('tr:first-child');
```

This will grab the first row no matter what (as long as there exists at least one row)