# Find field without a name in Mechanize

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to do the following scrape, but am having trouble finding the name of the form to input the zip codes.

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('https://www.wendys.com/en-us/Location')

wendy_form = page.form('find_loc') #name of the form

wendy_form.altZip = '10013' 
#altZip is the input form name

page = agent.submit(wendy_form)

page.search('p.store_address').each do |li|
  puts li.content
end
```

This is the form I am trying to get.

```
<form data-bind="submit: destinationFinder.huntViaAddressForm, visible: destinationFinder.isShowingResultsView() || ! routePlanner.destination.exists()" id="find_loc" style="">
```

Getting the following error:

```
2.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `altZip=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: right click the element and select inspect element and look for the name attribute in dev tools.

Comment: Already did. It is blank.

Comment: are there any other attributes on the element that you could use? ie id, class, element type

Comment: I am a relative noob. So I am sure there are but I don't know how to reference them in the code.

Comment: if you inspect element again and edit your question to have the exact line of the element your trying to target then I'd be able to help. ie `<input type=text id='foo' />`

Comment: There is a "copy css selector button" in chrome. see [how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome)

Comment: Already did that. Now I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html) I was able to find the following snippet.

```
form = page.form_with(:id => "find_loc")
```

This should target the form element you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix two issues:

- Find the proper form. For this you should use the id:

  `form = page.form_with(:id => "find_loc")`
- Use the correct way to set the altZip field:

  `wendy_form['altZip'] = '10013'`