# How do I convert a Chrome Selector path to a testCafe Selector

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe

How do I convert the selector string that I copy from chrome by using `Inspect > Copy > Copy Selector` to something that I can use inside of a testCafe Selector?

Chrome gives me this:

`body div#root div div.fullindy div.container div.row div.col-md-8 div form div.bd-graybackground.padding-64 div.row div.col-md-6 div.row div.col-md-6 div div.form.form-group div.css-10nd86i.clickable.normal-subheader div.css-1aya2g8 div.css-1rtrksz div.css-va7pk8`

This does not return `css-va7pk8` selector object that has a text value that I need to check.

This works:

```
Selector('form').find('.row').sibling().sibling(3).child(1).find('.row').child().find('div').child(1);
```

But this is very time consuming trying to figure out how to traverse a complex DOM. There has to be a faster way using the available features of Chrome and testCafe.

Comment: I would expect the structure of the selector copied from DevTools to look more like `#question-header > h1 > a`. Also displaying `body div#root` instead of just starting at `#root` is strange. Can you confirm that you're following the steps in this answer?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45078286/3456826

Comment: That is exactly how I am doing it. Some times it includes body but most of the time it starts with #root

Answer (score 3):

You can use the whole css selector string as a [TestCafe Selector constructor](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/constructor.html) parameter:

```
    await t.click(Selector(`body div#root div div.fullindy div.container div.row 
div.col-md-8 div form div.bd-graybackground.padding-64 div.row div.col-md-6 
div.row div.col-md-6 div div.form.form-group div.css-10nd86i.clickable.normal-subheader 
div.css-1aya2g8 div.css-1rtrksz div.css-va7pk8`));
```