# Selenium selects multiple elements with shadow dom

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I am working with the `chrome://extensions` page and I met some problems when trying to access a specific element using selenium. I am trying to get the extension id of an extension that I installed. The work flow is as follows: 
1. I go to the `chrome://extensions` page by using `driver.get()`
2. I get the "developer mode" toggle by using selenium element selector, and click the toggle so that extension id gets shown on the page.
3. I want to use multiple elements selector to select all "extensions-item" element on the page, find the specific extension that I installed, and retrieve the id. But I am stuck at this part because I am able to select one element but not multiple elements for some reason.

I have the following script:

```py
def expand_shadow_element(driver, element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script(
        'return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root

def get_extension_id(driver):
    root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("extensions-manager")
    shadow1 = expand_shadow_element(driver, root1)
    shadow2 = shadow1.find_element_by_css_selector("cr-view-manager")
    root3 = shadow2.find_element_by_id("items-list")
    shadow3 = expand_shadow_element(driver, root3)
    i = shadow3.find_element_by_tag_name("extensions-item") # This works fine, but it can only retrieve the first "extensions-item". What if I want the second one?
    print("finding single element successful")
    items = shadow3.find_elements_by_tag_name("extensions-item") # This line throws an error
    for item in items:
        shadow4 = expand_shadow_element(driver, item)
        if shadow4.find_element_by_id("name").text != "Chrome Automation Extension":
            return "Success"
    raise "Error"
```

The error message is as follows:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"extensions-item"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
```

Besides, I used `find_element_by_tag_name` instead of others because others do not work. To my understanding, even if I believe it is essentially the same as `find_element_by_css_selector`, but using this instead will throw element not found error. I do not understand why.

Anyone has any idea? I just don't know why I am able to locate one element but not a list of them. I am guessing it is because the way I manipulated shadow-dom, but through searching on the Internet I was not able to find another way of manipulating it. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Finding by tag name is for finding `a` tags, or `tr` tags, or `article` tags - valid HTML tag types. CSS selectors also support tag names, so if searching for all `<a>` tags you could use either method. But if you were looking for a link tag with the class `extensions-item' then you would need a CSS selector like `a .extensions-item'

Comment: Have you tried copying the CSS Selector or XPath directly to the element you want from devtools and drop that into a `find_element_by_css_selector` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome

Comment: @mgrollins But the name of the tag is `extensions-item`, are you saying it is not a valid HTML tag or something? Then in this case which should I use, if I am looking for a tag named `extensions-item`? No class or id or anything like that.

Comment: @mgrollins I tried copying the xpath but I don't think it works since the page has several levels of nested shadow-doms

Comment: Ah, I believe you are correct. This tag type is a valid HTML5 tag I believe, and also it appears you are correct that the "copy path" doesn't work due to shadow-doms. I seem to have misread your initial question

Comment: For the line where you assign `i` you should use the `find_elements_by_tag_name` to get a list of elements back. The word element is pluralized to `elements`

Comment: @mgrollins I managed to make it work by using css selector. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Phew! Glad I was able to help out a bit, I was doing some testing but do not have the experience working with shadow-dom.

Comment: That's because unlike classic LightDOM, the ShadowDOM specification only defines querySelector/querySelectorAll (which use CSS selectors) on the shadow root.