# How to select the sibling div with same class using css?

Tags: html, css

i have two divs with same class ".tools" within a parent div of class ".main". and these two divs of class ".tools" have buttons. i want to get the first button within first div of class ".tools"

below is the html

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="tools">
        <button class="icon"></button>// want to select this 
        <button class="icon"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="tools">
        <button class="icon another"></button>
    <div>
</div>
```

i have tried something like below

```
".main.tools > button:first-child"
```

but this doesnt work. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: You should use `first-child` on `.tools` as well: `.main .tools:first-child button:first-child`.

Comment: `.main .tools button:first-child` you need a space between .main and .tools

Comment: Read [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main>.tools:first-of-type>button:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="tools">
    <button class="icon">btn</button>// want to select this
    <button class="icon">btm</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <button class="icon another">btn</button>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main > .tools:first-of-type button:first-of-type {
  background: red;
  border: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="tools">
      <button class="icon">button 1</button>
      <button class="icon">button 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tools">
      <button class="icon another">button 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

select the first element within the `.main` class and then select the first `button`
Hope it'll help

Answer (score -2):

Put a `>` between `.main` and `.tools` to indicate that you want to select an immediate child. Since you also want to select the button inside the first class, add `:first-child` to the `.tools` too:

```css
.main > .tools:first-child > button:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="tools">
    <button class="icon">btn</button>// want to select this
    <button class="icon">btn</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <button class="icon another">btn</button>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Your current selector will only match a descendant of an element which has *both* `main` and `tools` classes.

Comment: But OP only wants to select the first button of the first `tools` element. In your case, you also selected the button of the second `tools` element

Comment: Oops, you're right. Having no button content there made its effect invisible

Comment: It has been corrected in the meantime obviously, so now it is a valid solution imho.