# Select specific element in HTML using CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's the HTML structure. This kind of data will be generated dynamically. It will have a few numbers of `<p>` tags with the class **c1** only, and a few numbers of `<p>` tags with the classes **c1** and **c2** both.

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="c1 ab">The 1st paragraph.</p>
    <p class="c1 cd">The 2d paragraph.</p>
    <p class="c1 ef">The 3rd paragraph.</p>
    <p class="c1 gh">The 4th paragraph.</p>
    <p class="c1 ij c2">The 5th paragraph.</p>
    <p class="c1 kl c2">The 6th paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

I need to select the last `<p>` tag with the class **c1** but not the class **c2** and apply styles to it. i.e. in the given sample code, I need to select and apply styles to the `<p>` tag with the classes **c1 gh**.

I wrote the following CSS code for the same. It selects all the `<p>` with the class c1, but don't know how to select the last element of such occurrence.

```
<style> 
.container p:not(.c2) { background: red; }
</style>
```

I used the following code for that, but it didn't work.

```
.container p:not(.c2):last-of-type { background: red; }
.container p:not(.c2) :last-of-type { background: red; }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Refer this to get correct selector https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth this only works in a fixed DOM structure.

Comment: you want last 2 background color red.. pls explain more

Comment: @Ranjithv I assume this is just a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can be done with the help of JS

Comment: @roy - how? `.container p:nth-last-child(1 of :not(.c2)) {
  background: red;
}` does not do it

Comment: @mplungjan please see my answer, it explains this usage.

Comment: @mplungjan yes, Its a **cross-browsing problem**, and is not a very good solution. I think the best way to arproach the problem is with `jQuery/Javascript` (sorry)

Comment: I am not understanding your question after reading so many times.If you only want to add some style to the 4th paragraph p tag then why you are not using this  "   p.c1.gh{style=""} .  "

Comment: @Anmoljuneja He clearly states _I need to select the last <p> tag with the class c1 but not the class c2 and apply styles to it_ so whatever many c1 tags there are, the last of them which do NOT have c2 should be accessed

Answer (score 1):

`:last-of-type` selects the last matching element. `:not(.class)` is only a condition applied after the selection. The selector creates an overlapping group of:

- `c1:last-of-type` = ["The 6th paragraph."]
- `:not(.c2)` = ["The 1st paragraph.", "The 2d paragraph.", "The 3rd paragraph.", "The 4th paragraph."]

These sets do not overlap, so the selector does not match any element.

---

I was trying to find a similar selector a while ago. There is development in CSS 3 selectors that might allow this. It allows you to do this:

```
p:nth-last-child(1 of :not(.c2)) {
    background: red;
}
```

**But at the time of writing this, [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child#Browser_compatibility) is poor.** The only browsers where it does work is Safari (macOS and iOS) 9+. So this solution is still not usable for most cases.

Alternatively, you can use `:nth-of-type(4)` if the element is always exactly the 4th elemet. Or you can use `:nth-last-of-type(3)` if the element is always exactly 2 elements before the last one.

```css
/* applicable only if the target element is always exactly 4th in .container */
.container .c1:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: red;
}


/* applicable only if the target element is always second to last */
.container .c1:nth-last-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
}


/* poor browser support (Safari 9+ at the time of writing) */
.container .c1:nth-last-child(1 of :not(.c2)) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="c1 ab">The 1st paragraph.</p>
  <p class="c1 cd">The 2d paragraph.</p>
  <p class="c1 ef">The 3rd paragraph.</p>
  <p class="c1 gh">The 4th paragraph.</p>
  <p class="c1 ij c2">The 5th paragraph.</p>
  <p class="c1 kl c2">The 6th paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

If none of this applies, JavaScript is a solution, but it will not work in cases when the script is blocked.

When I was looking to solve this, I've opted for is to edit the markup to add the class which identifies the element I was looking for.

Comment: I would assume it is because you do not access the last p not c2 but the 4th always

Comment: Maybe. But it's explained in which case it applies, I do not propose it as a general solution. Maybe misunderstood because I was not clear enough?

Comment: I'm upvoting, even though it's basically a long way to say "No, it's not possible. If it's a dynamically created list, made by javascript, then use javascript to add a specific class to the element you want to highlight".

Comment: @RickardElimää Thanks. That's true today, but this answer will be here in the future, when the complex selector list syntax is widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

Only with CSS it's not possible. The last-of-type Selector calls really the last of the p-tags and your condition effects only the last p-tag if it's not with the chosen class.

Your only way I see is, that you have to set a new class with your framework or with JS.

When you know, that the element is the 4th you could use :nth-child(4) or if it is the 3rd last :nth-last-child(3)

Answer (score -1):

CSS Property **nth-child** :

```
.container p:not(.c2):nth-child(4){ background: red; }
```

CSS Property **nth-of-type** :

```
.container p:not(.c2):nth-of-type(4) { background: red; }
```

CSS Property **nth-last-child** :

```
.container p:not(.c2):nth-last-child(3){ background: red; }
```

Comment: but what if there are more than 6 elements? then you have to change manually! Is there any solution to do it dynamically without js or jquery ??

Comment: Yes, if there are x number elements you have to change the CSS. 
Dynamically no from CSS its not possible. I can suggest you use a different approach here add any unique class or element to target the next sibling element.

Comment: You forgot to add `.gh` as an answer as well. :P