# Want to change Wordpress website navigation menu font but Why the style.css is empty?

Tags: css, wordpress

I want my Wordpress website navigation menu font larger And make the font become normal type, but NOT  capital letters.

I have googled it and the result said need to change the theme style.css in WordPress dashboard, based on the  tips but there has another issue, the style.css in my child theme is almost blank, only a few lines with the theme description (i.e. theme name / version / templates/ author etc.)  , but Not the site theme CSS. Is the theme creator hide the CSS?   So why this happened? And what should I do?

please see the screenshots below. 
[style.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkZPN.png)

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Your child theme inherits styles from the parent theme.

You can add your CSS rules to the empty file to override the parent styles.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So do you mean the empty is fine, just  add the  CSS in that place directly right?  I also use the Simple Custom CSS plugin, but no change, don't know why. If I want to change the menu nav font size and state( not capital ), what's the correct CSS style that should be? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use a code inspector ie. Chrome dev tools to make the changes you want to the existing style and copy/paste that code into your child theme stylesheet.

**EDIT**

In Chrome for example, open the code inspector using ctrl+shift+i might be different on a mac, I don't know. by default it will show you your html markup and your css styles below. Locate the element you want to change either by finding it in the html portion or using the selector tool (top-right of the developer window) and selecting the element you want to change on your page.

That will show you the css for that element that you can modify as you wish underneath. Once you are satisfied with the styles you have changed/removed/added, you can copy that code to your child theme css.

Other than that, I can only suggest you find some resources and videos on using dev tools to help you out. If you are building a child theme you will need to be using them significantly.

PS. One more thing to note is that some wp themes have some code that you can only really change with a plugin or by writing custom css under the customizer.

You can figure out exactly what you need to write in the custom css area by using chrome's dev tools and selecting the font you want to change.

Comment: thanks for the help. sorry I don't know code/develop, not sure what you mean exactly. May I ask so what's the "code inspector ie" / or what Chrome dev tool can let me change the style? Could you please explain more clearly? 

And I also use the Simple Custom CSS plugin, but no change, don't know why. 

If I want to change  the menu nav font size and state, what's the correct CSS style that should be?


 Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the themes also have a section where you can put custom CSS. You can usually find this in the Wordpress Customizer, otherwise in the theme settings. This way you are always sure it wont disapear after updating your theme. Of course you can also use a child theme, but the style.css above doesn't look like it is from a child theme.

The CSS you are probably looking for is the following:

```
.nav{
    font-size:14px;
}
```

If you don't know the correct CSS selector (.nav) you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome). To see what styles you should use for the element you can look at the [CSS Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/) of W3Schools. Hope it helps you.