# Python Selenium click()

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on the navigation tab 'MPass' however, it doesn't work.

https://www.gv.com.sg/GVMovies

```
nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.nav.nav-tabs')
tabs = nav.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.ng-binding')[1]

tabs.click()
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtCeW.png)

[overview[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYi1T.png)

Comment: Hi @Kim and welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Could you share a whole runnable code snippet, explain your expectations, and the result you are getting (e.g. errors, or getting wrong page etc.)?

Comment: Hi @HubertGrzeskowiak!! So basically, I'm trying to do web scraping on the following website and obtain the different movies that are showing, needs a mpass membership and also the upcoming movies. However, I am unable to navigate towards the mpass page using click() function. I am very new to stack overflow haha. Appreciate any help/guidance you can give me :)

Comment: @Kim  Use edit functionality to edit your post. There is no option to add files purposly. because you can add as part of question. use help section while editing your post. Dont add the screenshot of code add the code directly in the post. Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: It's just an element click intercepted exception due to an overlaying element.

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome> ,the second answer might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *full XPath*:

I am using Firefox web-driver(You can download it from [here](https://pycheat.com/download_img.php)):

```
from selenium import webdriver

site = 'https://www.gv.com.sg/GVMovies'

#providing driver path
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\Drivers\geckodriver.exe')


driver.get(site)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just invoke click on the a tag with M Pass Movies and bypass the element in front.

```
nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.nav.nav-tabs')
tab = nav.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='M Pass Movies']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are waiting for the element to load and visible in the dom.

and then use `find_element_by_css_selector`

```
selector = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li[select=\"changeTab('M Pass Movies')\"]")
selector.click()
```

or

```
selector = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li[class='tab-pane ng-isolate-scope']")[0]
```