# Get inner text of tags using Javascript Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, puppeteer

I am new to js and have been trying hours getting inner text of `bio__name__display` tag (see the attached DOM) and I am failing.
What could be the problem here?

I am calling async functions defined in *page.js* from *index.js*, and when I `console.log` the return value of a first function, it works fine. However the second function does not work (the output is `undefined`).

For CSS Selector, I tried the following but to no avail.

- `div.bio__name > span.bio__name__display`
- `"div.bio__name>span.bio__name__display"`
- `div.bio__name  span.bio__name__display`

#### index.js

```
const splinterlandsPage= require('./page');
.
.
.
await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
    let [mana, displayName] = await Promise.all([
        splinterlandsPage.checkMatchMana(page).then((mana) => mana).catch(() => 'no mana'),
        splinterlandsPage.getText(page).then((displayName) => displayName).catch(() => 'displayName name not caught')
    ]);

console.log("mana : ", mana)                   //works
console.log("displayName: ", displayName);     //does not work
.
.
.
```

#### page.js

```
.
.
.
// first function
async function checkMatchMana(page) {
    const mana = await page.$$eval("div.col-md-12 > div.mana-cap__icon", el => el.map(x => x.getAttribute("data-original-title")));
    const manaValue = parseInt(mana[0].split(':')[1], 10);
    return manaValue;
}

// second function
async function getText(page) {
    const displayName= await page.$$eval("div.bio__name > span.bio__name__display", el => el.innerText);
    return displayName
}
.
.
.
exports.checkMatchMana = checkMatchMana;
exports.getText= getText;
```

#### DOM

[image]

Comment: Please link to the actual site. Are you using `waitForSelector` before making the `$$eval`? Actual sites dynamically manipulate elements so there's no way to help without the actual, reproducible behavior on hand. A console screenshot shows the selectors would work, but the page might not be in that same state when Puppeteer runs. It's possiible that the elements don't exist or are buried in a frame or shadow DOM -- it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I wanted to share the actual site URL, it was tough to do so since the access to the DOM required a sign-up for the site and this specific DOM in question is available for only 2 minutes after a certain button within the site is clicked.

I finally figured them out myself today - below is a solution and some notes for later reference.

## Solution

The issue was not a CSS Selector but **what `$$eval` returned**.
Since `$$eval` returns a list of elements, the return value has to be processed like `el => el.map(x => x.innerText))` instead of `el => el.innerText`.

#### page.js

```
// second function
async function getText(page) {
    const displayName = await page.$$eval("div.bio__name > span.bio__name__display", el => el.map(x => x.innerText));
    return displayName[0]
}
```

Other workaround can be using `$eval` instead which returns a single matching element.

```
// second function
async function getText(page) {
    const displayName = await page.$eval("div.bio__name > span.bio__name__display",　el => el.innerText);
    return displayName
}
```

## Notes

#### `$$eval` and `$eval`

- [`$$eval`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) runs [document.querySelectorAll('CSS Selector')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) internally, which returns *multiple [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)s* that match the specified group of selectors.
  (**Also works when there's only a single element that matches, but the return value needs to be processed accordingly in `pageFunction[, ...args]`**)
- [`$eval`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) runs [document.querySelector('CSS Selector')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) internally, which returns *a single [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)* that matches the specified group of selectors.

#### CSS Selectors

As a new learner, I often find myself lost getting my head around choosing right Selectors.
Might be a quick and dirty way but [the first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500572/how-can-i-get-the-css-selector-in-chrome) helped.